# How can I get around Adobe AIR strict JavaScript sandboxing?

Tags: jquery, html, air, adobe, sandbox

I am building a desktop HTML application. I choose Adobe AIR for deployment because I am familiar with AIR from the ActionScript side and because it seems to hook into the desktop well.

However, I am finding that incorporating third party libraries (mainly jQuery libraries) is very difficult. Most libraries that I want to add tend to fall prey to AIR's strict sandboxing. Last night I wasted an hour looking for a DatePicker class that would work well with AIR.

I am pretty reliant on third party libraries and I would like to know if there is any good way to get past AIR's sandboxing (short of modifying all the libraries to remove the offending evals and what-have-you).

Or am I better off just switching to some other desktop HTML app framework that is more lenient about sandboxing? Not sure what alternatives would be better (perhaps Appcelerator)?

Edit: The app will mainly be communicating with a database and displaying results, but it needs some basic local file interaction, such as opening Word or Excel documents. It also needs to be in it's own app window (as opposed to say running locally in the browser).

Comment: What features are you needing from your platform?  Is using pure html5 not an option?

Comment: Something like http://www.pokki.com/ may work for you.

Comment: @Nik Edited question to reflect the app requirements. Thanks for the link, I will check it out.